# Can't set up Subscription Price for Auto Renewable subscriptions in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm trying to set up an auto-renewable subscription in App Store Connect. Whenever I try to set the price (by clicking on the + sign next to Subscription Prices, the pricing pop-up loads for a second and then I get a message saying "There was a problem retrieving the data for this page. Please try again".

Worse, I can't even update the price for subscriptions in existing apps. If I try, the same thing happens.

I've searched online for answers but all I can find is a lot of developers complaining about the same issue, which apparently has been going on for months.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: @SondreSørbye Hey! I did find a solution. I switched from an admin user to an app manager user and I was able to set price. Give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I switched from an Admin user to an App Manager user and it worked.

Comment: Did not work for me.